# Plasma's interaction with a gas

Tags: speed, plasma-physics, gas

I was told by my physics professor  that plasma, when accelerated and injected into a chamber, will slow down if a non ionic gas is Injected  into the stream at a angle. Knowing this, I have been trying to figure  out four things.

A: is there a equation for said interaction that describes this loss of speed

B: does the equation relate the angle at which these two interact?

C: how does the angle affect the loss in speed?

D: what is the thermal energy of the mixture after interaction?

I am assuming a ideal gas, and a uniform mixture in a contained system with a plasma injector at the center of a circle, with gas injectors repeating along that circle. the injection speeds will be extremely high, and the gas will be charge neutral

Comment: Are you thinking of situations like interstellar gas cloud collisions in cosmology? If so are plasma/gas collisions any more turbulent than gas/gas collisions?

Comment: @JohnRennie I edited my question to explain the scenario  in which this interaction will occur

Comment: The sort of system [described in this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0032-1028/13/2/004/meta)?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to access the full article, but it seems to be similar scenarios

Comment: Are you asking about charge-neutral collisional drag?  If so, then much of the interaction would be similar to two neutral gases colliding (ignoring recombination, spallation, and ionization).

Comment: @honeste_vivere that sounds similar  to what I'm looking for

Comment: @fftk4323 - If the neutral density is high enough then the result would be very similar to two neutral gases colliding because the long-range Coulomb potential of the charged particles would not matter to the neutral gas particles.  So long as the impacting speeds are low enough, the collisions will be similar to neutral-neutral collisions.